# Python Multi-lined Artificial enums using range

Tags: python, enums, range, multiline

I am trying to make an enum-type class in Python but it gets so lengthly when you have to do

```
VARIABLE1, VARIABLE2, VARIABLE3, VARIABLE3, VARIABLE4, VARIABLE5, VARIABLE6, VARIABLE7, VARIABLE8, ... , VARIABLE14 = range(14)
```

and I've tried to set it up like the following, but ended up not working.

```
VARIABLE1,
VARIABLE2,
VARIABLE3,
...
VARIABLE14 = range(14)
```

How would I accomplish this in the simplest way possible?

Comment: Why bother with enums in the first place?  What problem does it solve?

Comment: It helps me set error codes and etc...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Oh, wow I just added brackets around the variables and it worked

```
(VARIABLE1,
VARIABLE2,
VARIABLE3,
...
VARIABLE14) = range(14)
```

Comment: Sure, or alternately you could end each of those lines with the `\` line continuation character.

Comment: @bgporter do you mean ``\``?  Written in comments with escaping pattern `\`\`\\`\`` instead of `\`\\``.

Comment: Oops, yes, exactly. ``\``.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of manually typing VARIABLE1, VARIABLE2 ... you can do this:

```
>>> for x in range(1, 15):
        globals()['VARIABLE{0}'.format(x)] = x
```

Does what you want, without the extra effort of typing VARIABLE1 ... VARIABLE 14.

Comment: I was just using VARIABLE1, VARIABLE2... as an example, what I actually have would definitely not work with this for loop.

Comment: Best pythonic approach so far

Answer (score 3):

The explicit way of line joining is to use backslash characters:

```
VARIABLE1,\
VARIABLE2,\
VARIABLE3,\
...
VARIABLE14) = range(14)
```

and the implicit way is to enclose with parentheses, square brackets or curly braces:

```
[VARIABLE1,
 VARIABLE2,
 VARIABLE3,
 ...
 VARIABLE14] = range(14)
```

Answer (score 2):

Using the new [aenum](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aenum) library and Python 3 you can do:

```
from aenum import Enum

class SomeEnum(Enum, start=0):
    VARIABLE1
    VARIABLE2
    VARIABLE3
    VARIABLE4
    VARIABLE5
    VARIABLE6
    VARIABLE7
    VARIABLE8
    VARIABLE9
    VARIABLE10
    VARIABLE11
    VARIABLE12
    VARIABLE13
    VARIABLE14
```

and in use looks like:

```
>>> SomeEnum.VARIABLE7
<SomeEnum.VARIABLE7: 6>
```

Note:  `aenum` is written by the author of [enum34](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34)

Answer (score 2):

An enum implementation similar to `namedtuple` using `namedtuple`.  This `enum` function creates a class with `namedtuple` and instantiates the class with supplied arguments. Arguments are strings, `tuple` or `list`. The `tuple` or `list` form of arguments are used to supply a value to the constants thus resetting value sequence. By default, constants are valued starting from zero.

```
def enum(name, *args):
    from collections import namedtuple

    kwargs = {}
    start = 0
    for arg in args:
        if isinstance(arg, basestring):
            kwargs[arg] = start
            start += 1
        elif isinstance(arg, (tuple, list)):
            if len(arg) != 2:
                raise ValueError('"{}" must be a two element tuple or list'.format(arg))
            attr, start = arg
            if isinstance(attr, basestring):
                if isinstance(start, int):
                    kwargs[attr] = start
                    start += 1
                else:
                    raise TypeError('second element of "{}" must be of type "int"'.format(arg))
            else:
                raise TypeError('first element of "{}" must be sub type of "basestring"'.format(arg))
        else:
            raise TypeError('Argument "{}" must be either sub type of "basestring", "tuple" or "list" of ("basestring", "int")'.format(arg))

    if isinstance(name, basestring):
        return namedtuple(name, kwargs.keys())(**kwargs)
    raise TypeError('Argument "{}" must be an instance of "basestring"'.format(name))
```

Usage;

```
In [663]: Color = enum('Color', 'black', 'white', 'red')

In [664]: Color.black
Out[664]: 0

In [665]: Color.red
Out[665]: 2

In [666]: #To start from 1

In [667]: Color = enum('Color', ('black',1), 'white', 'red')

In [668]: Color.black
Out[668]: 1

In [669]: Color.red
Out[669]: 3

In [670]: Animal = enum('Animal','cat', 'dog', ['lion',10],'tiger')

In [671]: Animal.dog
Out[671]: 1

In [672]: Animal.tiger
Out[672]: 11

In [673]: Animal.tiger = 12
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-673-8823b3c2482c> in <module>()
----> 1 Animal.tiger = 12

AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

Answer (score 1):

By learning a bit about range function you can fix it in no time. Visit - [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range) for more details.
We see that the 2 apis(s) are: 
range(stop)
range(start, stop[, step])

Where it just returns a list of numbers in that particular range with step which is 1 by default.

Hence you just need to make sure that your code is compliant with that which you can do by explicitly telling python that they are the in the same line which you can do by adding '\' character at the end of every line.
Also if you enclose them by '[]' or '()' marking them as list of tuple, the python interpreter will implicitly treat it as a one line. Use the codes listed or experiment yourself to get more hang of it.

Answer (score 0):

Build the identifiers (variable) as strings like `'VARIABLE{}'.format(1)` and make a genexp which `yield`s 2-element `tuple`s consisting of the identifier and the value like `('VARIABLE1', 0)`.

This genexp can be used to feed a `dict` or `dict.update`. In The OP's case the `dict` is the one returned by `globals()`.

```
>>> globals().update(('VARIABLE{}'.format(x+1), x) for x in range(14))
>>> VARIABLE1
0
>>> VARIABLE14
13
```

If the values to be assigned are non-integers `enumerate` can solve the problem of variable naming.

```
>>> globals().update(('VARIABLE{}'.format(i), x) for i, x in enumerate('abcdefghijklmn',1))
>>> VARIABLE1
'a'
>>> VARIABLE14
'n'
```

Answer (score 0):

I find dictionaries often to be more suitable than enums, because they allow to easily map integers to more than one variable, function etc. For example assigning an in to a function and string:

```
import numpy as np,

CC = [(np.sin, "Taking the sine"),
      (np.cos, "Taking the cosine"),
      (np.tan, "Taking the tangens")]
dCC = dict(enumerate(CC, start=1))  # built the enumerated dictionary


def calc(n, x):
    """ Perform operation on `x` defined by number `n` """
    f, s = dCC[n]  # map number to function and string
    y = f(x)
    print(s + " from %g results in %g" % (x, y))
    return y

y = calc(2, np.pi)  # prints: "Taking the tangens from 3.14159 results in -1"
```